# how to implement RSA algorithm in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

i have implementing one login page.I have to send password in encrypt format to the server using RSA algorithm.But not working can u advice me for this query.

Comment: Beware that encryption will slightly complicate your app submission process.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329204/iphone-objective-c-rsa-encryption

Answer (score 2):

Check this C++ code: http://www.efgh.com/software/rsa.htm
It has both the key generation function as well as the encrypt/decrypt.
It even has an implementation for large integers which are needed for secure public-key cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CryptoExercise included with your iPhone SDK Documentation, it should point you in the right direction.